# Where should I place .desktop files for 3rd-party apps installed in /opt?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, desktop, xdg

Where am I supposed to put `.desktop` files for 3rd-party applications installed in `/opt`?

I can put them in `~/.local/share/applications` for each user but this is a maintenance nightmare. Preferably, I'd like to put them somewhere in `/opt` itself; however, how do I get the desktop manager (DM) to recognize these?

Does `XDG_DATA_DIRS` affect where the DM looks for `.desktop` files?
If so, would it be appropriate to add a script to `/etc/profile.d/` which appends a custom path to `XDG_DATA_DIRS`?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Place them in `/usr/local/share/applications/`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming (*a*) the DM uses `XDG_DATA_DIRS` to search for `.desktop` files, and (*b*) the 3rd party app's folder hierarchy within folder `/opt` is compliant with the [Desktop Entry Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html), then your idea of creating a script within `/etc/profile.d/` to modify `XDG_DATA_DIRS` is sensible, in my opinion.

For example, assume you install a 3rd party package named `xyz` into folder `/opt/xyz/`,

```bash
$ tar xf xyz-1.0.0.tar.gz
$ cd ./xyz-1.0.0/
$ sudo make install prefix=/opt/xyz/
```

and the installed package's file system hierarchy is as shown below:

```bash
/opt/xyz/
|-- etc/
|   `-- xdg/
|       `-- menus/
|           `-- applications-merged/
|               `-- X-Xyz.menu
`-- usr/
    |-- bin/
    |-- lib/
    |-- libexec/
    `-- share/
        |-- applications/
        |   |-- org.example-Xyz_CoolFeature.desktop
        |   `-- org.example-Xyz_AwesomeFeature.desktop
        `-- desktop-directories/
            `-- org.example-Xyz.directory
```

Adding the folder path `/opt/xyz/usr/share` to your `XDG_DATA_DIRS` environment variable

```bash
export XDG_DATA_DIRS=/opt/xyz/usr/share:${XDG_DATA_DIRS}
```

*should* have the desired effect, i.e., the DM should search

- within folder `/opt/xyz/usr/share/applications` for `.desktop` files, and
- within folder `/opt/xyz/usr/share/desktop-directories/` for `.directory` files.

Similarly, you can potentially customize the DM's applications menu via one or more `.menu` files stored within folder `/opt/xyz/etc/xdg/menus/applications-merged/`, and adding the folder path `/opt/xyz/etc/xdg` to environment variable `XDG_CONFIG_DIRS`:

```bash
export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/opt/xyz/etc/xdg:${XDG_CONFIG_DIRS}
```

EXAMPLE: */etc/profile.d/xyz-xdg-config.sh*

```bash
case "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" in
    'KDE' | 'ubuntu:GNOME' )
        export XDG_DATA_DIRS=${XDG_DATA_DIRS:-/usr/local/share:/usr/share}:/opt/xyz/usr/share
        export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=${XDG_CONFIG_DIRS:/etc/xdg}:/opt/xyz/etc/xdg
        ;;
esac
```

See also the [Desktop Menu Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/menu-spec-1.1.html) (v1.1).

For icon files, see: [What's the absolute path of an icon declared in a .desktop file?](https://askubuntu.com/a/66424/657351)